# Include a php file with SITE_URL but it's not working

Tags: php

I defined my site URL as SITE_URL now I am trying to include a php file with SITE_URL but it's not working.

My code is:

```
<?php
include_once ('<?php echo SITE_URL ?>/vendor/autoload.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can only include local files (unless you have `allow_url_include` set to `On` in your ini file), so you need to be using a relative or absolute file path, not a url.

Second, you can't use nested php tags. You'd want, general:

`<?php
include_once (SITE_URL.'/vendor/autoload.php');?>`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to echo the constant. You can simply concatenate it:

```
<?php include_once(SITE_URL . '/vendor/autoload.php'); ?>
```

Also, it seems unlikely that SITE_URL is what you want here. Usually you will use a "DOC_ROOT" or similar constant to indicate that you are accessing a local file (not a Web URL).